# ASCX and Jquery Dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

In my project i have a main aspx page. On that page i create a jquery dialog with multiple options. 
On click on 1 of the options, i load on an iframe a aspx with a place holder. Depending on the url i load a specific user control (ascx).

On that ascx i have a form for creating and editing users, i would like to change the jquery dialog title to show the name of the user being edited.

I've search but i can't find any awnser to this...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just use the 'title' option for jquery ui dialog when you initialize the dialog. If you need example, please provide some of your code here :)

Comment: The thing is i only want to update the title while on "edit mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window.parent to point the initial page then point to the selector of the div rapresenting the dialog and set the title with option-title attribute.

Example, in the iframe you can call:

```
window.parent.$('#<div_name>').dialog('option', 'title', 'New Title');
```

**EDIT**
This is the correct answer for your needs:

```
window.parent.$(window.frameElement.parentNode).dialog('option', 'title', 'newTitle');
```